# Serve my own HLS .m3u8 & .ts files over HTTP from Adobe Experience Manager for playback via Video.js

Tags: aem

I have created my own set of m3u8 and .ts files using FFmpeg. This set works perfectly when played via my video.js player, when served from Apache, Microsoft IIS, or NGINX. I wish AEM to perform the same simple server task.

How do I upload this set of files to AEM, so that they are not altered by AEM in any way, so I can play them via my video.js video player?

(I simply want to serve .m3u8 and .ts files over HTTP via AEM. I do not wish the files to be re-encoded, nor streamed via an Adobe video service of any kind.)